# Having trouble not to show "null" in swift, at mealDB

Tags: swift, swiftui

Thank you always to help me!!

I am having a trouble that not want to show if there is empty string or nil, but still see on view. if there is empty string, I can handle how to not showing them with function "showIngredient" but if there is nil, I don`t know how to not show it...

I have a problem with this link because this string has "null" but usually the other link have all string.

https://themealdb.com/api/json/v1/1/lookup.php?i=52768

don`t have a problem with this link

https://themealdb.com/api/json/v1/1/lookup.php?i=53049

please help me :))

Don`t have a problem with this:

[image]

I have a problem with this because this string has "null" but usually the other link have all string:

[image]

```
struct ShowIngredient: View {
    
    var mealDetail: Mealdetail?
    
    func showIngredient(ingredient: String?, measurment: String?) -> Text? {
          
            if ingredient != "" {
                return Text("\(ingredient ?? "") - \(measurment ?? "")").font(.callout)
            }
        return nil
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            showIngredient(ingredient: mealDetail?.strIngredient1, measurment: mealDetail?.strMeasure1)
            showIngredient(ingredient: mealDetail?.strIngredient2, measurment: mealDetail?.strMeasure2)
            showIngredient(ingredient: mealDetail?.strIngredient3, measurment: mealDetail?.strMeasure3)
            showIngredient(ingredient: mealDetail?.strIngredient4, measurment: mealDetail?.strMeasure4)
            showIngredient(ingredient: mealDetail?.strIngredient5, measurment: mealDetail?.strMeasure5)
            showIngredient(ingredient: mealDetail?.strIngredient6, measurment: mealDetail?.strMeasure6)
            showIngredient(ingredient: mealDetail?.strIngredient7, measurment: mealDetail?.strMeasure7)
            showIngredient(ingredient: mealDetail?.strIngredient8, measurment: mealDetail?.strMeasure8)
            showIngredient(ingredient: mealDetail?.strIngredient9, measurment: mealDetail?.strMeasure9)
            showIngredient(ingredient: mealDetail?.strIngredient10, measurment: mealDetail?.strMeasure10)
            showIngredient(ingredient: mealDetail?.strIngredient11, measurment: mealDetail?.strMeasure11)
            showIngredient(ingredient: mealDetail?.strIngredient12, measurment: mealDetail?.strMeasure12)
            showIngredient(ingredient: mealDetail?.strIngredient13, measurment: mealDetail?.strMeasure13)
            showIngredient(ingredient: mealDetail?.strIngredient14, measurment: mealDetail?.strMeasure14)
            showIngredient(ingredient: mealDetail?.strIngredient15, measurment: mealDetail?.strMeasure15)
            showIngredient(ingredient: mealDetail?.strIngredient16, measurment: mealDetail?.strMeasure16)
            showIngredient(ingredient: mealDetail?.strIngredient17, measurment: mealDetail?.strMeasure17)
            showIngredient(ingredient: mealDetail?.strIngredient18, measurment: mealDetail?.strMeasure18)
            showIngredient(ingredient: mealDetail?.strIngredient19, measurment: mealDetail?.strMeasure19)
            showIngredient(ingredient: mealDetail?.strIngredient20, measurment: mealDetail?.strMeasure20)
        }
    }
}

struct Mealdetail: Codable {
    var idMeal : String?
    var strMeal: String?
    var strCategory: String?
    var strArea: String?
    var strInstructions: String?
    var strMealThumb: String?
    
    // Ingredient
    var strIngredient1: String?
    var strIngredient2: String?
    var strIngredient3: String?
    var strIngredient4: String?
    var strIngredient5: String?
    var strIngredient6: String?
    var strIngredient7: String?
    var strIngredient8: String?
    var strIngredient9: String?
    var strIngredient10: String?
    var strIngredient11: String?
    var strIngredient12: String?
    var strIngredient13: String?
    var strIngredient14: String?
    var strIngredient15: String?
    var strIngredient16: String?
    var strIngredient17: String?
    var strIngredient18: String?
    var strIngredient19: String?
    var strIngredient20: String?
    
    // Measurements
    var strMeasure1: String?
    var strMeasure2: String?
    var strMeasure3: String?
    var strMeasure4: String?
    var strMeasure5: String?
    var strMeasure6: String?
    var strMeasure7: String?
    var strMeasure8: String?
    var strMeasure9: String?
    var strMeasure10: String?
    var strMeasure11: String?
    var strMeasure12: String?
    var strMeasure13: String?
    var strMeasure14: String?
    var strMeasure15: String?
    var strMeasure16: String?
    var strMeasure17: String?
    var strMeasure18: String?
    var strMeasure19: String?
    var strMeasure20: String?
}
```

I don`t want to see on my view, if there is nil.

Comment: Try putting your ingredients and measurements in a struct and then make an array of those structs, instead of 1, 2, 3, etc.

Comment: You should show your code that parses the JSON. Have you created structs that conform to Codable?

Comment: @koen, Can you let me know more detail...?

Comment: SwiftUI is not like other frameworks, to control what you want to show, you control the data to be displayed, not the views. So test the data, if it is nil or empty don't display, don't use `Text?`. There are many ways you can **not show** some data, eg compactMap, filter etc...
 
 Have a look at my test code at: https://github.com/workingDog/FreeMeal (just updated) that I showed you in your previous question. The code shows you how to call the (www.themealdb.com) server, get the data in the form of struct models, and display them in a list.